# Corona storyboard add objects to the [self.view] outside the methods

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am aware that I need to put all the display objects in my scene into the group view.

But I need to prepare dynamic display view and in far depth functions [not directly called from `scene:createScene`, `scene:enterScene` etc.]

So I tried making a global reference of the `self.view` but it did not help. Here's my code snippet:

```
-- reference all variable
local globalSceneObj

function scene:createScene(event)
    print ( "scene:createScene" )
    local group=self.view
    globalSceneObj=group
    ..
    ..
 end


function enterObject()
      ..
      ..
    currentFlyingObj=display.newImage(globalSceneObj,FLYING_OBJECTS[num][1],display.contentWidth,_H/2)
      ..
      ..
end
```

But this code does not help and my game crashes when I visit this screen the second time. Is there any other way to get reference of the Storyboard group view?

Comment: are you purging the scene between transitions? if so the view will get destroyed

Comment: Firstly, is this global referencing a correct method? and yes i am purging scene on scene:destroyscene function

Comment: you could try using getCurrentStage() and get the view from that instead of using the global var https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/getCurrentStage.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach ,

--refrence all variable
    local globalSceneObj

```
function scene:createScene(event)
 print ( "scene:createScene" )
 local group=self.view
 scene._globalSceneObj = group
..
..
end



function enterObject()
  ..
  ..
 currentFlyingObj=display.newImageRect(FLYING_OBJECTS[num] [1],display.contentWidth,_H/2)
 scene._globalSceneObj:insert(currentFlyingObj)
  ..
  ..
 end
```

And make sure while moving to other scene you are removing the current scene and all you are cancelling all the timers using timer.cancel(timername) and the remove the listeners if you are using them .